# Three js print canvas causes problems in content flow below

Tags: canvas, printing, three.js

I faced a weird problem when using theee.js libary and printing from browser.

I want to print a simple canvas to a document like a pdf doc.

What i tried so far (option 1):

1. download the canvas from screen and save it locallly
2. make a div and a img child within where i load the downloaded image
3. fill page with content -> click print()

This works like a charm.

For downloading and saving img i use filesaver.js and this function:
`

```
jQuery('#screenshot').click(function () {
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                renderer.domElement.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "Configurator");
                });
            });
```

`

But i cannot force every customer to download and then upload the picture .. that would be a mess and somehow this is not possible at all. ^^

Better idea would be to (option 2):

1. convert the canvas to a jpg or png with js
2. make a div and append the image just converted
3. add content below img -> click print()

This doesn't work as expected. The image gets shown but content gets somehow cropped of when exceeding the first page. But this is not the case when using (option 1). But it is the same .. there is a image .. there is the same content but instead of it gets cropped it gets simply shown on a new page (page 2) which is fine.

Function for transforming:
`

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('print');
            mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", () => {
            
             renderer.setClearColor(0xff0000, 1);
             renderer.render(scene, camera);
             var canvasNew = document.getElementsByClassName( 'realCanvas' );
             console.log(canvasNew);
             var highQuality = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
             var img = new Image();
             img.src = highQuality;
             img.width = 1024;
             img.height = 600;
             console.log(img);
             var container2 = document.getElementById( 'tableCanvasIMG' );
             //container2.appendChild(img);
             container2.append( img);
             
            });
```

`

The canvas which gets converted looks like this:
[image: converted canvas img]

The pdf which comes out has only one page and content gets cropped of which should be visible on page 2:
[image: printed pdf]

But when i use option 1 which means to simply add an img to a div which was downloaded right before - this works as you can see the content which exceeds page 1 is visible on page 2. (same img width, height)
[image]

the html code:
`

```
<div id="tableprint">
    <!--<div id="tableCanvas"></div>-->
    <div><img src="files/configurator.png" /></div>
    <!--<div id="tableCanvasIMG"></div>-->
    <div id="tablesssss" style="overflow:visible !important;">
        <div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">first <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">Model <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">Model <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">Model <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">Model <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">Model <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">Model <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">Model <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">Model <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">Model <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">vorlast <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
<table align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:50%;">
    <tr>
        <td><th colspan="0">last <span style="color:red">Funtrain</span></th></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px;">
    <th colspan="1">Hauptfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Sekundärfarbe</th>
    <th colspan="1">Dritte Farbe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td >Ral 5050</td>
    <td >Ral 3020</td>
    <td >Ral 7040</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>


<p> some text </p>
<p>some text 3 </p> 
    </div>
```

`

I would like to have the same functionallity from option 1 working in option 2.
In my opinion this has something to do with the canvas element or the base64 encoded img. How is this possible that it's working with a simple image but not with a canvas.
Anybody have a clue to force the browser to display he overflow or to force a new page.

I also tried different css solutions (overflow:visible !important, page-breaks etc..), i removed every floating css, every inline display and so on.. nothing has lead me to an acceptable solution.

Comment: I solved it by using a plugin called "printjs". It's curious that there is no simple solution for that, instead i had to use another plugin, but OK it works.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists with Mozilla Firefox on mobile devices but this cannot be fixed as firefox has disbaled some print functions on mobile